# How connect deployed rails app to exist Heroku database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, credentials

I launched my Rails application on Heroku. 
And I want to connect it to the database of an existing project of my friend, which is also deployed on Heroku. A friend gave me credentials and url to the database. However, I do not understand how to connect my project to my friend's database. I tried to change `DABASE _URL` but all is useless. Also, credential data was placed in `database.yml` and when I run the `heroku run db:setup` in the heroku terminal i get

`FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
Couldn't create '*************' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege`

Comment: No need to add credentials in database.yml. You only need to update DATABASE_URL under Config Vars. heroku does not allow to run db:setup command.

Answer (score 2):

Use following steps:

1) Add `DATABASE_URL` (complete url username, password, host) under settings / Config Vars.

2) For Rails apps you should look to use `db:schema:load, db:structure:load` or `db:migrate` instead of `db:setup`.

here is more info about issue https://help.heroku.com/63D7ALXT/why-am-i-seeing-user-does-not-have-connect-privilege-error-with-heroku-postgres-on-review-apps

You can share a single Heroku Postgres database between multiple apps with the heroku addons:attach command

```
heroku addons:attach my-originating-app::DATABASE --app new_app
```

for more info check here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#sharing-heroku-postgres-between-applications

hope this helps

Comment: Item could not be updated:
Cannot overwrite attachment values DATABASE_URL

Comment: pls explain me: what means "my-originating-app::DATABASE" and "new_app". which app i should overwrite instead of

Answer (score 2):

The reason you cannot update `DATABASE_URL` is because it's currently pointing at another database without any auxiliary attachments. This is a safety mechanism to prevent users from accidentally shooting themselves in the foot. This should allow for your changes.

1. `heroku addons:attach <addon name, eg postgresql-cloudy-12345> --as ORIGINAL_DB --app <app name>`

   - This will create an additional attachment name so you don't lose reference to the original database
2. `heroku addons:detach DATABASE_URL --app <app name>`

   - This will remove the Heroku-managed `DATABASE_URL` config var.
3. `heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=<the connection string for the other database> --app <app name>`

   - This sets `DATABASE_URL` to point at the other database which should put things into an operable state.*

* This caveat here is that this is a brittle configuration because hostnames can change for databases. If the db undergoes maintenance you will need to manually change the config var (ie repeat step 3).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this situation by going to heroku.com to my app then setting then Config Vars
The DATABASE_URL was different than the ORIGINAL_DB_URL so I changed the DATABASE_URL to be similar to ORIGINAL_DB_URL
In my case: postgres://quxhxkemlsfzzv:964c7..........